# Como evitar repetição de código para calcular a média de uma quantidade variável de notas

Tags: python

Criei um script simples para poder retirar a média dos alunos com mais facilidade.

O problema é que possivelmente eu precisaria de um `while` para repetir o código. Queria fazer com que, quando terminasse de exibir a média de um aluno, voltasse e perguntasse novamente qual seria as notas.

Código:

```
print('----------------MÉDIA DO ALUNO----------------')
qn = int(input('Quantas notas são? [2,3,4,5]: '))
d = int(input('As notas serão dividas por quanto? '))
if qn == 2:
    n1 = float(input('Qual a primeira nota? '))
    n2 = float(input('Qual a segunda nota? '))
    m1 = n1 + n2
    mm = m1 / d
    print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(mm))
if qn == 3:
    n1 = float(input('Qual a primeira nota? '))
    n2 = float(input('Qual a segunda nota? '))
    n3 = float(input('Qual a terceira nota? '))
    m1 = n1+n2+n3
    mm = m1 / d
    print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(mm))
if qn == 4:
    n1 = float(input('Qual a primeira nota? '))
    n2 = float(input('Qual a segunda nota? '))
    n3 = float(input('Qual a terceira nota? '))
    n4 = float(input('Qual a quarta nota? '))
    m1 = n1+n2+n3+n4
    mm = m1 / d  
    print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(mm))
if qn == 5:
    n1 = float(input('Qual a primeira nota? '))
    n2 = float(input('Qual a segunda nota? '))
    n3 = float(input('Qual a terceira nota? '))
    n4 = float(input('Qual a quarta nota? '))
    n5 = float(input('Qual a quinta nota? '))
    m1 = n1+n2+n3+n4+n5
    mm = m1 / d 
    print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(mm))
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo Caio, leia está [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421991/110782) acredito que seja  o que você quer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está com muita repetição desnecessária. A ideia para eliminar esta repetição é identificar o que se repete e o que varia, e colocar tudo isso em um *loop*. No caso, o que varia é a quantidade de notas, mas há um padrão que se repete: leio as notas, somo e calculo a média.

Outro detalhe é que tendo a quantidade de notas, não faz sentido ter outro número para dividir. Por exemplo, se eu tiver 3 notas, faz sentido dividir a soma delas por 10 para calcular a média? Não, eu divido por 3, que é a quantidade de notas (assumindo que você quer a média aritmética - se fosse média ponderada, por exemplo, precisaria ler os pesos, mas o código indica que provavelmente quer a média aritmética mesmo). Ou seja, a variável `d` do seu código não é necessária.

E se quer repetir esse processo várias vezes, coloque tudo isso dentro de um *loop*. Enfim, uma maneira de resolver é:

```
print('----------------MÉDIA DO ALUNO----------------')
while True:
    try:
        quantidade = int(input('Quantas notas são? [2,3,4,5] (0 para encerrar): '))
        if quantidade == 0:
            break

        if 2 <= quantidade <= 5:
            notas = []
            for i in range(quantidade):
                notas.append(float(input('Qual a {}ª nota? '.format(i + 1))))
            print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(sum(notas) / len(notas)))
        else:
            print('Quantidade de notas deve estar entre 2 e 5')
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número válido')
```

`while True` é um *loop* infinito: ele executa "para sempre", ou até que seja interrompido (seja pelo `break`, seja por algum erro).

Eu incluí uma condição de parada: quando a quantidade é zero, ele sai do *loop* (o `break` interrompe o `while`).

Há também um bloco `try`/`except` capturando o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), que é a exceção que ocorre caso [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) ou [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) não consigam converter o que foi digitado para número (por exemplo, se o usuário digitar `"xyz"`, dará este erro e cairá no bloco `except`). Neste caso, eu só imprimo uma mensagem e volto para o início do *loop*, pedindo novamente que digite a quantidade.

Depois eu verifico se a quantidade está entre 2 e 5, que parecem ser as opções válidas. Se for, eu prossigo com outro *loop* para ler as notas. Aqui eu uso um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) para iterar pelos números. No caso, `range(quantidade)` cria a sequência dos números de zero a `quantidade - 1`. Em seguida, leio as notas e vou guardando na lista `notas`.

Aliás, este `for` é o que mencionei no início: identifique o que varia e o que se repete para criar o *loop*. O que varia é a quantidade de notas a serem lidas, e isso é controlado pelo `range`. O que se repete é o que está dentro do `for`: a leitura de uma nota.

Por fim, eu exibo a média. Para isso eu uso [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), que soma os valores da lista, e [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), que retorna o tamanho da lista (eu também poderia ter usado a própria variável `quantidade`).

Depois de imprimir a média, ele volta para o início do `while`, ou seja, pede para digitar a quantidade de notas novamente.

---

O `for` também pode ser trocado por uma [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052):

```
if 2 <= quantidade <= 5:
    notas = [ float(input('Qual a {}ª nota? '.format(i + 1))) for i in range(quantidade) ]
    print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(sum(notas) / len(notas)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu código está com muita repetição. Se eu fosse você eu usaria dois `while`, no primeiro eu colocaria um recurso de parada, como por exemplo: “Digite ‘sair’ para terminar o programa, ex:

```
print("Digite ‘sair’ para finalizar o programa")

while True:

    quantidade_notas = input("Digite a quantidade de notas que serão inseridas:")
    if quantidade_notas == "sair":
        break
        # codigo
```

Já dentro desse eh colocaria um repetiria a quantidade de notas que seriam inseridas, ex:

```
while True:
    quantidade_notas = input("Digite a quantidade de notas que serão inseridas:")

    if quantidade_notas == "sair":
        break

    while quantidade_notas > 0:
        # codigo de print e scan
        quantidade_notas = quantidade_notas -1
```